# {{ kint() }} leads to install.php

Tags: 8, debugging

Just on certain pages, I'm led instead to /core/install.php...

This has happened to me a great number of times now, in certain twig templates.  But, I can't imagine why.  Has anyone else had this happen?  What causes it?  It just doesn't work in some templates.  I'm only asking this because I have never seen anyone ask anything like it, and it has happened to a coworker as well.

Comment: I've had the same issues. Although I've never found out the reason of this behaviour, my advice is to use [Twig Tweaks](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) and print variables with `{{ dd(my_var) }}`. Doesn't cause any redirects and is a LOT faster than kint.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me about that, although for future reference I'll note that I didn't realize you had to run 'composer require symfony/var-dumper' to get the function to work.  I like the UI better than kint, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That will be caused by an overload on resources. `kint()` is very resource intensive. If you are calling **kint** in a `views-view-files.html.twig` template for example then it could get called multiple times and overload the system.

If you check your logs you'll find an error like this:

`General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away`

The DB has been overloaded and Drupal thinks there's no install, hence ending up on the install page.

Here are three ways of limiting the **kint** maxLevels variable which can help avoid this. Set maxLevels to 3 or 4.

1) In `settings.php`:

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/modules/contrib/devel/kint/kint/Kint.class.php';
Kint::$maxLevels = 3;
```

2) In `/modules/contrib/devel/kint/kint/` duplicate the `config.default.php` file to `config.php` and modify this line:

```
$_kintSettings['maxLevels'] = 3;
```

3) In a preprocess function, add the following:

```
kint_require();
Kint::$maxLevels = 3;
```

---

You can also filter the kint output so it only shows the KEYS, e.g.

```
{{ kint(_context|keys) }}
```

---

Alternatively, use [Symfony var-dumper](https://github.com/symfony/var-dumper) which is a bit more lightweight:

```
composer require symfony/var-dumper
```

Visit the **devel** settings page and set **Symfony var-dumper** as the **Variables Dumper**.

Example usage:

```
{{ devel_dump() }}
{{ kpr() }}
{{ dpm() }}
```

Comment: Just adding to this: In windows, XAMPP, the settings for mysql is set to too low and cause this issue on DB intensive tasks. Increasing that will definitely help.

Comment: As Anish says you can also increase the amount of resources available. But how you do this can vary a lot depending on your development environment. I really encourage developers to look into https://www.docker.com/ if you have not already. There is a bit of a learning curve but once you get into using containers you will not look back!!!